# Akka Http - Host Level Client Side API Source.queue pattern

Tags: scala, akka-http, akka-stream

We started to implement the `Source.queue[HttpRequest]` pattern mentioned in the docs: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/client-side/host-level.html#examples

This is the (reduced) example from the documentation

```
val poolClientFlow = Http()
  .cachedHostConnectionPool[Promise[HttpResponse]]("akka.io")

val queue =
  Source.queue[(HttpRequest, Promise[HttpResponse])](
     QueueSize, OverflowStrategy.dropNew
  )
    .via(poolClientFlow)
    .toMat(Sink.foreach({
      case ((Success(resp), p)) => p.success(resp)
      case ((Failure(e), p))    => p.failure(e)
    }))(Keep.left)
    .run()

def queueRequest(request: HttpRequest): Future[HttpResponse] = {
  val responsePromise = Promise[HttpResponse]()
  queue.offer(request -> responsePromise).flatMap {
    case QueueOfferResult.Enqueued    => responsePromise.future
    case QueueOfferResult.Dropped     => Future.failed(new RuntimeException("Queue overflowed. Try again later."))
    case QueueOfferResult.Failure(ex) => Future.failed(ex)
    case QueueOfferResult.QueueClosed => Future.failed(new RuntimeException("Queue was closed (pool shut down) while running the request. Try again later."))
  }
}

val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] = queueRequest(HttpRequest(uri = "/"))
```

The docs state that using `Source.single(request)` is an anti-pattern and should be avoid. However it doesn't clarify why and what implications come by using `Source.queue`.

> At this place we previously showed an example that used the `Source.single(request).via(pool).runWith(Sink.head)`. 
>   In fact, this is an anti-pattern that doesn’t perform well. Please either supply requests using a queue or in a streamed fashion as shown below.

## Advantages of Source.queue

- The flow is only materialized once ( probably a performance gain? ). However if I understood the akka-http implementation correctly, a new flow is materialized for each connection, so this doesn't seem to be that much of a problem
- Explicit backpressure handling with `OverflowStrategy` and matching over the `QueueOfferResult`

## Issues with Source.queue

These are the questions that came up, when we started implementing this pattern in our application.

### Source.queue is not thread-safe

[The queue implementation is not thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43013771/is-connection-pooling-in-akka-http-using-the-source-queue-implementation-thread). When we use the queue in different routes / actors we have this scenario that:

A enqueued request can override the latest enqueued request, thus leading to an unresolved Future.

**UPDATE**

This issue as been addressed in [akka/akka/issues/23081](https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/23081). The queue is in fact thread safe.

### Filtering?

What happens when request are being filtered? E.g. when someone changes the implementation

```
Source.queue[(HttpRequest, Promise[HttpResponse])](
    QueueSize, OverflowStrategy.dropNew)
  .via(poolClientFlow)
  // only successful responses
  .filter(_._1.isSuccess)
  // failed won't arrive here
  .to(Sink.foreach({
    case ((Success(resp), p)) => p.success(resp)
    case ((Failure(e), p)) => p.failure(e)
  }))
```

Will the Future not resolve? With a single request flow this is straightforward:

```
Source.single(request).via(poolClientFlow).runWith(Sink.headOption)
```

### QueueSize vs max-open-request?

The difference between the `QueueSize` and `max-open-requests` is not clear. In the end, both are buffers. Our implementation ended up using `QueueSize == max-open-requests`

### What's the downside for Source.single()?

Until now I have found two reasons for using `Source.queue` over `Source.single`

1. Performance - materializing the flow only once. However according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43015133/709351) it shouldn't be an issue
2. Explicitly configuring backpressure and handle failure cases. In my opinion the ConnectionPool has a sufficient handling for too much load. One can map over the resulting future and handle the exceptions.

thanks in advance,
Muki

Comment: Muki, for each connection there's a materialization, not for each request.

Comment: Thanks Heiko :) I changed the description

Comment: similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46435647/akka-stream-akka-http-lifecycle?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer each of your questions directly and then give a general indirect answer to the overall problem.

**probably a performance gain?**

You are correct that there is a `Flow` materialized for each `IncomingConnection` but there is still a performance gain to be had if a Connection has multiple requests coming from it.

**What happens when request are being filtered?**

In general streams do not have a 1:1 mapping between Source elements and Sink Elements.  There can be 1:0, as in your example, or there can be 1:many if a single request somehow spawned multiple responses.

**QueueSize vs max-open-request?**

This ratio would depend on the speed with which elements are being offered to the queue and the speed with which http requests are being processed into responses.  There is no pre-defined ideal solution.

**GENERAL REDESIGN**

In most cases a `Source.queue` is used because some upstream function is creating input elements dynamically and then offering them to the queue, e.g.

```
val queue = ??? //as in the example in your question

queue.offer(httpRequest1)
queue.offer(httpRequest2)
queue.offer(httpRequest3)
```

This is poor design because whatever entity or function that is being used to create each input element could itself be part of the stream Source, e.g.

```
val allRequests = Iterable(httpRequest1, httpRequest2, httpRequest3)

//no queue necessary
val allResponses : Future[Seq[HttpResponse]] = 
  Source(allRequests)
    .via(poolClientFlow)
    .to(Sink.seq[HttpResponse])
    .run()
```

Now there is no need to worry about the queue, max queue size, etc.  Everything is bundled into a nice compact stream.

Even if the source of requests is dynamic, you can still usually use a Source.  Say we are getting the request paths from the console stdin, this can still be a complete stream:

```
import scala.io.{Source => ioSource}

val consoleLines : () => Iterator[String] = 
  () => ioSource.stdin.getLines()

Source
  .fromIterator(consoleLines)
  .map(consoleLine => HttpRequest(GET, uri = Uri(consoleLine)))
  .via(poolClientFlow)
  .to(Sink.foreach[HttpResponse](println))
  .run()
```

Now, even if each line is typed into the console at random intervals the stream can still behave reactively without a Queue.

The only instance I've every seen a queue, or `Source.ActorRef`, as being absolutely necessary is when you have to create a callback function that gets passed into a third party API.  This callback function will have to offer the incoming elements to the queue.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Unfortunately this doesn't answer any of my questions. Your _general redesign_ section exactly describes the anti-pattern referenced in the documentation. There's no difference between `Source.single` and `Source.fromIterator` with a single element. 

The goal is to make simple http requests and get the response as a `Future[HttpResponse]`. The `cachedHostConnectionPool` takes care of connection pooling. Nothing the API user has to deal with.

Comment: @Ramon J Romero y Vigil I'm trying to understand this: `Now there is no need to worry about the queue, max queue size, etc.` Is backpressure implicitly being handled with `fromIterator` and is that *always* a good thing? Also, an *infinite* `Queue` has `offer` method, but how would an Akka HTTP server route do the equivalent of `offer` (or sending incoming messages) from the route to the `fromIterator` source? For instance, can [finite use cases of fromIterator inside a route](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/source-streaming-support.html) be generalized to infinite?