# akka-stream + akka-http lifecycle

Tags: scala, akka-stream, akka-http

TLDR: is it better to materialize a stream per request (i.e. use short-lived streams) or to use a single stream materialization across requests, when I have an outgoing http request as a part of the stream?

Details: I have a typical service that takes an HTTP request, scatters it to several 3rd party downstream services (not controlled by me) and aggregates the results before sending them back. I'm using akka-http for client implementation and spray for server (legacy, will move to akka-http over time). Schematically:

`request -> map -1-*-> map -> 3rd party http -> map -*-1> aggregation -> response`

This can be achieved either by materializing a stream per request or materializing (parts of) stream once and share it across requests.

Materializing per request incurs materialization overhead<sup>1</sup> and it is not clear how to leverage connection pools with it. The problem is described [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/client-side/pool-overflow.html) (many materializations can exhaust the pool). I can wrap a pool in a long-running http stream like [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/client-side/host-level.html#using-the-host-level-api-with-a-queue) and wrap in a `mapAsync` "upstream", but the error handling strategy is not clear to me. When a single request fails and the stream is terminated, would it take down the pool as well? More, it seems I will need to reconcile requests and responses since they are not returned in order.

```
// example of stream per request

val connectionFlow = Http().cachedHostConnectionPool[UUID](host, port)
val httpFlow: Flow[HttpRequest, Try[HttpResponse], NotUsed] =
    Flow[HttpRequest]
      .map(req => req -> UUID.randomUUID()) // I don't care about id because it's a single request per stream.
      .via(connectionFlow)
      .map { case (response, _) => response }

val result = Range(1 to 5).foreach{ i => {
  Source.single(i)
    .map(HttpRequest(...))
    .via(httpFlow)
    .mapAsync(1) {
       // response handling logic
    }
    .runWith(Sink.last)
})


// example of stream per request with long running http stream

// as defined in http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/client-side/host-level.html#using-the-host-level-api-with-a-queue
def queueRequest(request: HttpRequest): Future[HttpResponse]

val result = Range(1 to 5).foreach{ i => {
  Source.single(i)
    .map(HttpRequest(...))
    .mapAsync(1)(queueRequest)
    .mapAsync(1) {
       // somehow reconcile request with response?
       // response handling logic
    }
    .runWith(Sink.last)
})
```

Sharing stream across requests has a similar issue of error handling - it seems that there are failure modes that can bring down that stream with all requests in-flight. The code will be similar to [host level API](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/client-side/host-level.html#using-the-host-level-api-with-a-queue), but with the queue fronting the whole stream.

Which way is better in this case?

I did try to implement both solutions, but there are many design choices at every stage of implementation, so it seems easy to screw up even on a "right" path.

<sup>1</sup>Although I believe it is negligible, and it is the same way akka-http server operates.

Answer (score 1):

In general it is much better to use a single connection `Flow` and dispatch all of your requests through that single Flow.  The primary reason is due to the fact that a new materialization may actually result in a new `Connection` being formed each time (depending on your connection pool settings).

You are correct that this results in a few complications:

**Ordering**: By providing a random `UUID` as the 2nd value in the tuple 
 that you are passing to the connection flow you are eliminating your ability to correlate a request to a response.  That extra `T` value in the tuple can be used as a "correlation id" to know which `HttpResponse` you are getting from the Flow.  In your particular  example you could use the initial `Int` from the `Range` you created:

```
val responseSource : Source[(Try[HttpResponse], Int), _] = 
  Source
    .fromIterator( () => Iterator range (0,5) )
    .map(i => HttpRequest(...) -> i)
    .via(connectionFlow)
```

Now each response comes with the original Int value which you can use to process the response.

**Error Handling**: You are incorrect in stating "a single request fails and the stream is terminated".  A single request failure DOES NOT necessarily result in the stream failing.  Rather, you will simply get a `(Failure(exception), Int)` value from the connection flow.  You now know which Int caused the failure and you have the exception from the flow.

Comment: Thanks Ramon! My problem is that I don't really have a `Source`, every input to the stream is a request to http serves, so at most I have `Source.single`. How would I get a single flow in this case?

Comment: Additionally, how would I handle request timeout in a single Flow? The only timeout I was able to find is `completionTimeout` stage, but it fails a stream, not propagating an error downstream.